# How can I make my Google Form manage unique questions for an interview committee?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-forms, multiple-choice

I want the members of an interview committee to fill out a Google Form that will help manage which questions they will each ask the candidates they are interviewing.  I don't want a candidate to be asked the same question by multiple interviewers.

Step 1, they select from among 96 "competencies," e.g., "Accountability" might be a competency they believe the position requires.  They can choose up to, let's say, 5 competencies.

Step 2, based on which competencies they selected, they can now choose interview questions. We have a bank of 970 potential interview questions, each one of them directly related to one of the competencies.  As interviewers select questions, those questions should be eliminated as options for the other interviewers.  [I found some code to support the elimination part of this step in AppScript.  What I CANNOT figure out is how to make the list of questions also based on which competencies they selected in the prior step.  They should be choosing from a short list, not from a list of all 970.  Each competency only has a handful of questions tied to it.]

Step 3, once everyone has completed the Form, we can produce a doc or pdf so everyone on the committee can see what everyone else is asking.

Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, Google Forms are not suitable for your task. You can find Add-Ons and GAS example codes that can change, for example, options for some dropdown question.

The problem is those changes are reflected to all the form viewers/users, in your case interview committee. Think about it like you have a single Google Doc file, "Terms and Conditions" that you can edit and others can view. Google Form are designed with a "same for everybody" idea in mind, so you can see answer percentages right away, like you have poll on twitter.

What you can do, since you already played with GAS is to create GAS WebApp that presents different options for each user. But if you are beginner I wouldn't recommend this, you will have to be GAS + JuniorWeb developer at least. Plus, since users can work concurrently, you will have to double check if what user selected became unavailable meanwhile (after competencies are selected, while you are picking the questions someone maybe submitted one of your competencies, when you hit submit your selections are invalid, you'll have to do it again).

The simplest way is if you have a company website, to ask the website developer to make some kind of company portal (employees only, not visible to visitors). Then to create this tool you need and put it on the company portal.

I saw some solutions for "race for resources" in Google Sheets where you can have competencies listed, then one true/false checkbox column "Reserved" and one "Who Reserved" column. And the filter is set to hide Reserved=true (filters rows for everybody, "live"). Then users can "collaborate" and user is aware if something they wanted became unavailable second ago. "Who Reserved" would require GAS code to handle onEdit event. But you have a second level - questions, I have no idea how you could make this.

Comment: Thank you.  This gives me some ideas.  Maybe it's overcomplicating it to make a form, when they could just type their name next to the question that are reserving.  Will just have to try to find a way to make the long list not so intimidating.